# Pytorch: set top 10% values of the tensor to zero

Tags: python, pytorch

I have Pytorch 2d tensor with normal distribution.
Is there a fast way to nullify top 10% max values of this tensor using Python?

I see two possible ways here:

1. Flatten tensor to 1d and just sort it
2. Non-vectorized way using some native Python operators (for-if)

But neither of these looks fast enough.

So, what is the fastest way to set X max values of a tensor to zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it seems that Pytorch has a useful operator torch.quantile() that helps here a lot.

The solution (for 1d tensor):

```
import torch

x = torch.randn(100)
y = torch.tensor(0.) #new value to assign 
split_val = torch.quantile(x, 0.9)
x = torch.where(x < split_val, x, y)
```

Comment: Well, it seems that torch.quantile() is still pretty slow (probably uses non-optimal algorithms and tries to sort the tensor values).  torch.median() is faster but it can change only 50% so not always suitable. Some approach to resolve this issue could be using (torch.max() + torch.where()) instead to remove values > 70% * torch.max(). Latter is the fastest, but not exactly what we need...